# How to arrange canvas created dynamically?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

What I want to achieve is

[image]

Here is my code which didn't manage to give me the result i want. How come? I tried before Canvas.x.style.float also doesn't work...

http://jsfiddle.net/Jg2w4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I simplified it a bit for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/LrkZn/25/

I'd strongly suggest letting CSS layout the items instead of trying to finagle with absolute positions.

Comment: Note: on JSFiddle the JavaScript goes in a different pane from HTML.

Comment: Why does "element.setAttribute ('width', width)" not work for the button? Instead "element.style.width = width + 'px'" works? What's the difference?

Comment: `element.setAttribute ('width', width + 'px')` would probably work, but I think you need the  'px'

Comment: @yeeen You would want `el.setAttribute('style','width:'+width+'px')`; there is no `width` attribute for random elements, but there is a `style` attribute with its own custom formatting of "sub-properties".