# Why the rect created in the canvas doesn't follow the width n height stated?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a div, inside the div I have a canvas and I need to create a rect in the canvas..

```
this.canvas = {
            innerElement: TBE.CreateRectCanvasElement (Element.config.displayWidth, Element.config.displayHeight)
        };
    this.canvas.innerElement.style.border = '1px solid black';
    this.innerElementCtx = this.canvas.innerElement.getContext("2d");
    this.innerElementCtx.fillStyle = '#3ac6e5';
    this.innerElementCtx.fillRect(50, 50, 100, 100);
```

but the rect turns out to be not 50px n 50px away from the top n left and the height is much greater than the width... Why?

http://jsfiddle.net/dpQ64/3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because you did not set the width and height of the `<canvas>` in the HTML.
It is default to be in `1:1` ratio, and since you make it `100:300` in CSS, its width shrinks by `1/3`.

Comment: What is the difference btn setting it in html vs css?
I hv once ask this qn (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8032434/how-to-arrange-canvas-created-dynamically), the ans given suggested tt i use css instead of html, cos html one doesn't work...

Comment: HTML defines its size, and setting different size in CSS will stretch it.

Comment: Btw, after adding the setAttribute for width n height to my codes, it works! But how come HTML in the case of the other qn I asked doesn't work, but CSS works? thx

Comment: @yeeen, Congratulation! :) and just think it like this: HTML sets its size, and CSS stretches it.